Response 403 - Is it me or them?
I am using pyetfdb-scraper to scrap info about ETFs. It worked last week, but suddenly, I am consistently getting 403 errors.
from pyetfdb_scraper.etf import ETF
test = ETF('VTI')

How can I check that the server-side is blocking me, versus something wrong with the code?
Note that I am not doing a massive scrapping - I'm looking up half a dozen with 5 sec. sleep in between.

If you do the math, that's 100,000 requests per day.  A volume cap seems likely.

I don't follow your reasoning to 100,000. I'm querying 6 items, with a sleep of 5 second between them. That's still 6 items, no?

I assumed you meant "6 items, then 5 second delay, then 6 items, then 5 second delay".  That's 100,000 requests per day.  Perhaps I misinterpreted.

A 403 Forbidden error indicates that the server received and understood your request. However, it explicitly chose to forbid your request rather than actually serve it.
This can happen for a few different reasons (incorrect permissions, expired API keys, etc.), but it can also mean that the server has chosen to block your requests. Looking at the library, it doesn't seem like you need to register for an API key, so it's likely that you were timed out or IP banned due to too many requests.
